# Transpose columns to rows with aggregation values from multiple columns as keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I transform this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

The initial query I run is as below:

```
    select * from

(select a.curr_djf as date, 
replace ((replace (a.channel_group, 'iSelect', 'Aggregators')), 'Other Aggregator', 'Aggregators') channel,
sum(a.pols) pols, sum(a.pmplseu) pseu

from [DW_PHI_BASE].[dbo].[phdr_daily] a
and a.curr_djf between '2020-04-20' and dateadd(day,-1, cast(getdate() as date))
group by a.channel_group, a.curr_djf) d
```

I have tried to use pivot and cross apply but failed. My last attempt was using cross apply:

```
    select
    d.*
    from
    (select a.curr_djf as date, 
    replace ((replace (a.channel_group, 'iSelect', 'Aggregators')), 'Other Aggregator', 'Aggregators') channel,
    sum(a.pols) pols, sum(a.pmplseu) pseu

    from [DW_PHI_BASE].[dbo].[phdr_daily] a
    where
a.curr_djf between '2020-04-20' and dateadd(day,-1, cast(getdate() as date))
    group by a.channel_group, a.curr_djf) d

    cross apply (values
    ('pols', pols),
    ('PSEUs', pseu),
    ) x(channel, value)
```

and I am getting below error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Please help me to understand how to fix the table to the proper format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

```
Select [Date], channel, measure, [value]
FROM dbo.phdr_daily
UNPIVOT
([value]
FOR measure
IN([pols], [pseu])
)
AS Unpivoted_Results
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version should be fine, although you do want to select the correct columns:

```
select d.date, d.channel, x.*
from (select d.curr_djf as date, 
            replace(replace(a.channel_group, 'iSelect', 'Aggregators'), 'Other Aggregator', 'Aggregators') as channel,
            sum(d.pols) as pols, sum(d.pmplseu) as pseu
      from [DW_PHI_BASE].[dbo].[phdr_daily] d
      where a.curr_djf between '2020-04-20' and dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
      group by a.channel_group, a.curr_djf
    ) d cross apply
    (values ('pols', d.pols),
            ('PSEUs', d.pseu),
    ) x(channel, value);
```

I suspect that you really want to aggregate by `channel`, not `channel_group`, but that is another matter.